# How to ignore one element in css?

Tags: css

I have a menu effect where it underlines the heading of the menu you hover on, the problem is that it also underlines the logo when you hover on it...

The logo is in an li with the class name `.centered-inline-logo-wrap`
I just need to know how to ignore that when the bottom effects are triggered...

```
#top-menu .current-menu-item a::before,
#top-menu .current_page_item a::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
#top-menu li a:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -2;
 left: 0;
 right: 100%;
 bottom: 50%;
 background: #FFF; /*** COLOR OF THE LINE ***/
 height: 3px; /*** THICKNESS OF THE LINE ***/
 -webkit-transition-property: right;
 transition-property: right;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
 transition-duration: 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
 transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
#top-menu li a:hover {
 opacity: 1 !important;
}
#top-menu li a:hover:before {
 right: 0;
}
#top-menu li li a:before {
 bottom: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Please share your HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be able to use the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector, as in:

```css
#top-menu li:not(.centered-inline-logo-wrap) a:before
```

The `li:not(.centered-inline-logo-wrap)` portion would be `li` elements that do not have the class `centered-inline-logo-wrap`.

Comment: But it's messed up my sub menu lines...not sure why. :/ (it strikes through the text instead of being under it)

Comment: @yoyo Probably shouldn't use it on the sub-menu rule `#top-menu li li a:before`

Comment: I use it on the `#top-menu li a:before ` rule.

Comment: @yoyo Because of the way you're implementing the line, it seems that you need it to exist, but just not be visible when it's the logo. Maybe instead of using `:not()`, add a rule `#top-menu li.centered-inline-logo-wrap a:before { background: transparent; }`. This will give you the spacing that the underline provides but it won't appear visually.

Comment: Yeah seems so, that worked though! Thanks for the help mate, will mark correct answer.